# SWiftUI - Check if object exist in core data and return a boolean

Tags: swift, swiftui, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I'm trying to use a NSPredicate to filter items in core data if a value exist or not but i want to return a boolean so I can add it to core data if the result is false and remove it if it's true.

```
func addItem(item: String) {
    let newItem = CoffeeFavorite(context: managedObjectContext)
    newItem.title = item         
    saveFavorites()
}

private func deleteFavorite(title: String) throws {
    let request: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "CoffeeFavorit            
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "title == %@", title)
    try managedObjectContext.execute(NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: request))
}
```

I'm using these 2 function to add and delete items from core data but I need another one to check if the item exists so I can use one instead of the other with an if statement.
I guess I need to match a predicate that returns a boolean but I don't know how to do it